# How to connect a mongodb bi connector through python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-biconnector

How to connect a mongodb bi connector through python?
Is pymongo can do it? If yes can please provide some example with the authMechanism PLAIN(LDAP)?

I had try to connect with the pymongo but seems like it does not work for mongodb bi connector as it return error "got responce id xxxxxxxxxx but expected xxxxx".

The code I had tried

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Replace 'localhost' with the hostname or IP address of your BI 
Connector server
host = 'localhost'
port = 27017  # Default port for MongoDB

# Connect to the MongoDB BI Connector without specifying username 
and password
mongo_uri = f"mongodb://{host}:{port}/"
client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)

# Now you can use the 'client' object to interact with the 
MongoDB BI Connector
# For example, you can access databases and collections like 
this:
db = client['your_database_name']
collection = db['your_collection_name']

# Perform your operations on the collection here
```

I had replace the hostname and port with the Mongo db bi connector which works in java but is unable to work, this code does what for the MongoDB.

Is MongoDB and MongoDB bi connector using the same way to connect?
Or is there any documentation I can follow? (I didn't find any in pymongo official site)

Comment: Could you add some of the code you tried?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @James  i had add some new info in the question thanks.